# How to provide Activity in Dagger-Hilt?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I'm injecting a constructor of a view-model class which takes an Activity as parameter along with some other parameters. But can't provide Activity in module.

Comment: Injecting an `Activity` into a `ViewModel` via its constructor will definitely cause a memory leak on configuration changes if using `ViewModelProvider.Factory` with a `ViewModelProvider` - A ViewModel scope can out live an`Activity` instance.  Not to mention it kind of breaks MVVM as an architecture.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible or not, But I think you have to change your strategy, I think it's not appropriate to do that.

Answer (score -3):

I have done it by adding qualifier and providing the activity from module. Something like that,

```
@Provides
@SomeActivityScope
@Singleton
fun getSomeActivity() : Activity{
    return SomeActivity as Activity
}
```